# Change Jenkins default view

Tags: view, jenkins

I have been trying to follow the instructions on how to change the default view in Jenkins [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Editing+or+Replacing+the+All+View).

I've created another view that I would like to be the default, but when I go looking for the `Default View` setting in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` it doesn't seem to be there.  Is there something I have to do to make it show up?  Or is it tucked away somewhere else?

If someone has it working can they indicate where about in the config screen (immediately before/after something else) so I can double check.

I am using Jenkins 1.447

Answer (score 117, accepted):

from comment> When I go to `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` and `Default View`, all our "public" views are listed there in the drop down.

Make sure the view you created isn't just in "My Views" for your user, and is open to everyone.

Answer (score 37):

"Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System" >

The default view option is just after the "SCM checkout retry count" and before "enable security"

See below:

[image]

You should not have to change anything to have it show up. You might need more than one view, but it seems you have already created another one...

Answer (score 15):

You can only choose between default views when you have more than one view.  So first, create a new view by clicking the '+' mark on the Jenkins dashboard:

[image]

Of course, the '+' will only appear if you have permission to create new views.

Now, navigate to *Manage Jenkins* > *Configure System*.  The *Default View* option appears.  Using this you can select the default view.

The above applies to Jenkins 1.536.

Answer (score 1):

To change the default view in **Jenkins** go to Jenkins Dashboard:

Select **Manage Jenkins** --> **Configure System** --> **Default view**

Default view will be available after SCM checkout retry count in **MAVEN Project Configuration** .

Select your applicable **View** and Save and you're done.